# understanding linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am having trouble understanding linked lists from my course. The biggest problem I seem to have is how the data is stored. I see the code mainly `add(x)` add a new node in the list but it does not seem to make sense.

The code for add.

```
boolean add(T x) {
  Node u = new Node();
  u.x = x;
  if (n == 0) {
    head = u;
  } else {
    tail.next = u;
  }
  tail = u;
  n++;
  return true;
}
```

This is directly from the textbook of the course I am taking. I went online to find more resources and I found this code on GITHUB from a far more detailed textbook [Source](https://bitbucket.org/syncfusion/data_structures_succinctly_part1/raw/3dd92ce3785071e417cd28d41440a92c6eec8540/code/ADS_LibraryCode.cs). The code is far to long to just paste.

so over all I see classes named 'Head' 'Tail' and 'u' storing information like `[Head]->[u]->[Tail]`. Further as I read the add method I visualize the stored information look like `[Head]->[u]->[u]->[u]->[Tail]`.

How does each node know which 'u' node to look at. Each one is referencing `u` node. Either `u` is being over-rided each time, or getting `u` info will return all the `u`'s value's. how does the `node.next` differentiate each `u` node? Shouldn't the code rather than:

```
add(x) {
  Node u = new Node();
  u.x = x;
}
```

be more like:

```
add(x,y) {
  Node y = new Node();
  u.x = x;
}
```

So each node has a different name to link to `[Head]->[a]->[b]->[c]->[Tail]`

Comment: Rather than understanding linked lists, it seems like you need to spend some time to better understand the concept of object instantiation and scope in Java in general. However, to answer your last question: No, the code should not be what you have proposed.

Comment: `u` is just known inside the `add` method. It's the name you give to the newly created node inside the method, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable names itself do not matter in the sense that you think they do. `u` is just pointing to an instance of Node.

Let's say you want to create a linked list of integers:

You do `add(1)`. At this point, `n=0`.
In the `add` method, a new node is initialized. We just refer to it as `u`.  Now, we set the value to be `1`. Till now, we have created a `Node` with its value equal to `1`.

Since, `n=0`, our `head` will also now refer to this Node. We increment, `n++`, to keep track of the current length of the list. We also make our `tail` refer to the newly added node because we always add to the *end* of the list.

Now, you do `add(2)`. At this point, `n=0`. In the `add` method, a new node is initialized. We just refer to it as `u`.  Now, we set the value to be `1`. We don't need to update the head since `1` is the first node of list.

But, we need to add `2` to the end of the list. This means that the `tail` has to refer to the *newly* created Node whose value is 2. So, how do we do that? Well, `tail` as of now has been referring to the node whose value is 1. So, we just update that node's next to point to the same node that `u` is pointing to (since this is the newly created Node that we want to add to the end of the list).

To finish off, we will increment `n` and set our `tail` to point to the node we just added.

Comment: Ok so Node is not like other classes where each on needs a unique label. u is just the reference to a Node and the Node's themselves are managed through java. so effectively it looks like [Node 0 (head)]->[Node 1 (u)]->[Node 2 (tail)]. That makes sense.

Comment: @DrewS I guess you're still confused. `u` is just the name you give to the new node inside the `add` method. Outside of it, it's just a Node, it's not labeled. In the linked list you know the `head` and the `tail`, and you can reach the other `Node`s from the links of them.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to add a node to your linked list.

This creates the node `u`, with the respective info `x`.

```
Node u = new Node();
u.x = x;
```

---

Now, there's 2 options:

A - this is the first node you're adding to the linked list

B - there are already node(s) on the list, and you're adding another one.

This is where the if enters.

```
if (n == 0) {
  head = u;
} else {
  tail.next = u;
}
```

A - If `n` (the counter of nodes in the list) equals 0, then it's empty. So, the node `u` is the head of it.

B - Otherwise, you're adding a new node after the actual `tail` of it, so you add a reference to the actual `tail` saying this node will be the next one.

---

And finally, you have to say that the node you're adding is the new `tail` of the linked list (if it's empty, then `u` will be `head` and `tail`simultaneously). You also need to increment the counter of nodes `n`.

```
tail = u;
n++;
```

Answer (score 0):

From java.util.LinkedList the Node class described as below:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;
    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

Node holds both next and prev nodes, so every node knows its previous and next node.